# Java command works but javac command doesn't

Tags: java, java-8, javac

I just install jdk and jre version 8 In windows. Environment variable already set. I try run "java -version" in cmd and it shows the version of java installed. But when I try to compile java project with "javac projectName" system says javac is not recognized as internal or external command. So can anyone tell me how to fix it?

here is my environment variable:

> C:\Users\Foody>echo %PATH%
> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
> Corporation\Ph
> ysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\Sy
> stem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
> Installer ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
> Pages\v1.0;C:\Program Fi les (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows
> Performance Toolkit;C:\Program Files\Microso ft SQL
> Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
> Files\lenovo\easyplu ssdk\bin;C:\Program
> File\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program File\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;
>
> C:\Users\Foody>

Comment: double check env variables

Comment: Sounds like you may have the JRE installed rather than the JDK... or at least, only the JRE in your path. You say "Environment variable already set" - it would really help if you'd show what your path actually is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in your variable path:

```
C:\Program File\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program File\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\;
```

Should be and you do not need it twice

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;
```

Comment: thanks it's work. i cant think clear. but why it's work for java command before?

Comment: because your java is located under another directory

Answer (score 2):

The JRE only contains the java executable, and not javac. So apparantly your path points to the JRE installation dir, not the JDK.

Comment: No. The path contain is "C:\Program File\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin

Comment: @MahfudMuhammad and if you CD to that directory can you run javac?

Answer (score 1):

if the above text is correct, you have written

```
"C:\Program File\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program File\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\;"
```

it must be "Program Files"

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\
```

Answer (score 0):

On a windows system also check the if the path variable includes you're java installation. Use

```
set
```

Perhaps you want also want to have look at 
[Oracle Java help](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Regards
Patrick